# Master Detail Flow with Fragment or Activity

Tags: java, c#, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm making an Android app from which the user can choose content to read.
There is a list of books, and once the user chooses one, it opens a new screen with the content, and a second navigation drawer for navigating through the book.

I'm not sure if this screen should be a fragment or an Activity. I see a lot of recommendations to use fragments, but if you choose a Master/Detail Flow template in Android Studio, it creates an **Activity** for the details (at least for small screen sizes).
Why is this?

I'd be happy for some guidelines and explanations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically fragments were introduced for larger screens. You need two screens, one for list of books and one for viewing the contents of a selected book. You can write two fragments, one for each screen.

For tablets, you will have a single activity divided into two parts, one for each fragment.

For smaller screens, it depends on you and what you want to achieve. You can use a single activity with the fragment containing list of books and replace the fragment with the one that shows the contents when book is clicked. Or, you can start a second activity to show the contents and attach the fragment on it.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to know which option is better for small screens, and why Google choose a details activity if a fragment is recommended to use when you can. Any idea?

Comment: There are no specific hard rules. The core idea of master/detail layout is to divide screens into fragments so that larger screens can display both at the same time. For smaller screen, try both approaches and find out which suits you more. You don't need to follow what Google does for you. Do what you think is more suitable.

Comment: Ok. I'll try and see what fits me more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i would  recommend  use `fragments`
 with small screen devices and use the `master-detail` in TAB screen to make sure use of all empty space in large screens

Comment: In the Master/Detail template it's the opposite: Activity for small screen and a fragment for tablet screen, to use up the space and put it all on the same screen. The question is, why do they use an Activity for the small screen?